# How to check domain on email property by Bean Validation API based with regular expression

Tags: java, spring, pattern-matching, javabeans, bean-validation

I have the class student using Bean Validation API :

```
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@NotBlank
@Pattern(regexp="^$|^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$",message="Veuillez insérer email valid.")
private String email;
```

the domain of email should be like this :

azert@ecole.com
or
aqwxcs@ecole.com
or
ecole@ecole.com

However , domain should be finished by @ecole.com

How to check domain on email property by Bean Validation based on regular expression ?

Comment: Just try hardcoding that in the pattern: `regexp="^(?:[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(?:[.][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@ecole[.]com)?$"`

Comment: FYI This is Java Bean Validation API, and nothing to do with the JPA API (which is simply for communication to/from the DB). Updated question to correct it